# How to use the AlertDialog's return value

Tags: android, synchronization

In mostly situation, I need the user to make a choice many times.( I do something and raise a message box for the user to make a choice and continue do other thing(maybe called block))
So I wrote a common function

```
public static void ShowMsgDialog(Context self,String title, String msg)
```

Although it correctly response the user’s action, but always pending (that means while I click the button, the previous action's value is visible by global variable’s value) 
Is there exist any function which I could got the message box's return value and use it like this:

```
int ret = ShowMsgDialog(Context self,String title, String msg);
```

the follow is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button1;
    enum Answer { YES, NO, ERROR};
    static Answer choice;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ShowMsgDialog(MainActivity.this, "Information", "you choice? "); 
                if(choice == Answer.YES)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CHOICED YES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else if (choice == Answer.NO)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CHOICED NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR OCUS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //int ret = ShowMsgDialog(MainActivity.this, "Information", "you choice? ");  
            }
        });     
    }

    public static void ShowMsgDialog(Context self,String title, String Msg){
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(self);
        dlgAlert.setTitle(title);
        dlgAlert.setMessage(Msg);
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // call your code here
                choice = Answer.YES;
            }
        });
        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                choice = Answer.NO;
            }
        });
        dlgAlert.show();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that there is any way to get a value from an alertDialog
like this

```
int ret = ShowMsgDialog(Context self,String title, String msg);
```

because by the time your dialog will be shown the onClick() of your Button will have already finished.

So i suggest using another way to implement this.

Since the method to create the alertDialog is inside your activity it is as easy as creating a function in your activity like below:

```
public void userChose(String choise){

         if(choice == Answer.YES)
            //YOUR CODE FOR YES HERE
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CHOSE YES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         else if (choice == Answer.NO)
            //YOUR CODE FOR NO HERE
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CHOSE NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

and call your method in onClick()

like this:

```
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                userChose(Answer.YES);
            }
        });
        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                userChose(Answer.NO);
            }
        });
```

Comment: in different function, i intend to use the function's return value. if use global variable, then i do not know which the values for

Comment: which function call made the  value of answer variable, i don't know

Comment: i can't understand what you mean sorry, can you write it better? :S , but i believe that the only valid solution to get a return value is by calling another function which will update your UI according to your needs, because, when you show an AlertDialog there is no way to tell when the dialog will be closed from the user, and you cannot just pause the UI Thread and wait until a value from alertDialog is returned. So you need to use something like my example.

Comment: `"choosed" != "chose"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to show toast in the Positive and negative button Click event. because when you click on button alert shows up and after that if condition executes so that you have value from last opened alertview button click. so its is wrong. try this:

```
public static void ShowMsgDialog(Context self,String title, String Msg){
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(self);
        dlgAlert.setTitle(title);
        dlgAlert.setMessage(Msg);
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // call your code here
                choice = Answer.YES;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CHOICED YES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                choice = Answer.NO;
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CHOICED NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        dlgAlert.show();
    }
```

Comment: Toast a message is a sample, realities i use other code to instead it,i means just use the AlertDialog's return value.

Comment: you can't get the return value for alertbutton click without clicking on it. so you need to do something on alert button clicks.  call any function  on button clicks with alert button values.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't directly return a value from an AlertDialog, you could send the answer to an activity's handler:

```
public static void ShowMsgDialog(Context self,String title, String Msg){
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(self);
    dlgAlert.setTitle(title);
    dlgAlert.setMessage(Msg);
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // call your code here
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.arg1 = HandlerMessage.Yes.ordinal();
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);                
         }
    });
    dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.arg1 = HandlerMessage.No.ordinal();
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg); 
        }
    });
    dlgAlert.show();
}

enum HandlerMessage
{
    Yes,
    No
}

/** for posting authentication attempts back to UI thread */
private final IncomingHandler mHandler = new IncomingHandler(this);

static class IncomingHandler extends Handler 
{
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivityWeakReference; 

    IncomingHandler(MainActivity activity) 
    {
        mActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        MainActivity activity = mActivityWeakReference.get();
         if (activity != null) 
         {
             activity.HandleMessage(msg);
         }
    }
}
public void HandleMessage(Message msg)
{
    HandlerMessage handlerMessage = HandlerMessage.values()[msg.arg1];

    switch(handlerMessage){
        case Yes:
                //Do something ...
                break;
            case No:
                //Do something ...
                break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use an `Interface` for this (works at least with Java 8 and Java 11):

```
interface ResultHandler {
    void result(Answer choice);
}
```

Swift (iOS) has a really useful concept called "completion handler", which is a (sub-)function that's called once an operation has finished and that can also pass a result back to the calling function. This works in a similar way (but with Java):

You pass the handler to the second function as a parameter, call its function there when needed and can then work with the results in the first function afterwards. The great things are that this also works with functions of two different classes, it gets right back into the calling function and it's possible to access the calling function's variables from within this "sub-function" (they might have to be `final` though).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            ShowMsgDialog(MainActivity.this, "Information", "you choice? ", new ResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void result(boolean myresult) {
                    //Do something with the result here
                }
            });  
        }
    });     
}

public static void ShowMsgDialog(Context self,String title, String Msg, ResultHandler handler){
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(self);
    dlgAlert.setTitle(title);
    dlgAlert.setMessage(Msg);
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            handler.result(Answer.YES);
        }
    });
    ...
    dlgAlert.show();
}
```

This also works with multiple parameters, of course.